# Which ORM syntax to join three tables in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-views, django-queryset

I have the following three Models (tables) in my Django project:

```
class Tool(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', unique=True, max_length=50)

class Flow(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)
    Toolid = models.ForeignKey(Tool, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ToolId')
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', unique=True, max_length=50)

class Task(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=50)
    FlowId = models.ForeignKey('Flow', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='FlowId')
```

I want to make ORM query that returns all info of Tool, Flow, and Task together that are related to each other (i.e. JOIN method in SQL queries). For example, I want to get something like this:

```
[
 { Tool name: ...
   Flow name: ...
   Task name: ...
 }
 { Tool name: ...
   Flow name: ...
   Task name: ...
 }
 ...
 ...
]
```

Do you know what ORM sentence should I write to get that output?
I really want to get the result from all of the three tables (not only from two of them)!

It would be really appreciated if you provide me with the syntax related to my tables I provided above.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Task` has a foreign key for its `Flow`, which has a foreign key to `Tool`, you should be able to retrieve them all in one query like:

```
task_flow_tool_tuple_list = Task.objects.all().values_list('name', 'FlowId__name', 'FlowId__Toolid__name')
```

You use the 'dunders' (double-underscores) to link from model to model, and finally to the attribute you want from the last model in the chain. So we are selecting all the Task objects, and for each we are returning a list of:

- the Task name
- the Task's FlowId's name
- the Task's FlowId's Toolid's name

Hope that helps, happy coding!

Comment: Thanks! I am new to ORMs, and that really helped :)